# Отмена действий скрипта при перезагрузке (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, если я запущу вот такой скрипт (power.sh):

```
echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode #активирует laptop_mode
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host4/link_power_management_policy
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host5/link_power_management_policy
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host6/link_power_management_policy
echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  
echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor
echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  
echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor
echo 1 > /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings
echo 90 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
echo 60000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
echo powersave > /sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy
echo 10 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

То после перезагрузки всё станет так, как было до применения этого скрипта? Т. е. отменит ли перезагрузка изменения, который произвёл этот скрипт?

Comment: скорее всего да, кроме этой строки

    echo 1 > /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings

если только файл `sched-mc-power-savings` не является каким то хитрым симлинком.

Comment: IMHO записав 1 в /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings.conf Вы включите оптимизацию по энергопотреблению в планировщике и после перезагрузки.


    /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings.conf
    
    The sched-mc-power-savings module allows you to tune the Linux   kernel process scheduler to optimize for power usage on multi-core and multi-processor computers.

См. [Man laptop-mode.conf](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/8/laptop-mode.conf/#/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings.conf_1696h)

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, файловые системы /sys и /proc - виртуальные, после перезагрузки изменений в них не будет. В вашем случае, после вашего скирпта останется только один след:

```
echo 1 > /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings
```

Советую сохранить копию этого файла перед запуском скрипта.

```
cp /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings.backup
```